# Sorting by integer as boolean in mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have rails app with mongoid model. There's counter field in this model which is integer. I want to sort entries by this field casted to boolean, like

```
MyModel.desc("counter::boolean") # casting in postgres-like syntax
```

so entries with counter > 0 go first and those with counter == 0 go last.

I also use created_at sorting on this expression which works correctly only for same value of counter, that's why i need to have only two possible values. Not necessarily true/false, it could be 1/0.

Mongodb doesn't support custom sorting functions (there's open ticket for it).

Is such casting it possible to do in mongoid/mongodb? If no, maybe any workarounds?

Comment: Are you getting all documents? Can't you sort in the app?

Comment: sorting the number by desc will get your desired result too no need to cast it as boolean

Comment: @Sammaye, sorry, my description is confusing. I also have sort by created_at which works only for same counter values. I'll add it to question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I prefer to avoid sorting in application if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pretty way, but you might create additional field in documents with value depending exactly on your sorting scheme, like: "order": cast a value to boolean and then sort by it.
Suprisingly - it's a quite common way to get around mongodb's limitations.